# Differences between `decltype(&ordenary_func)` and decltype`(ordenary_func)`

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers, implicit-conversion, decltype

Given the declaration `void close_file_func(std::FILE* fd){}`, I found that `decltype(&close_file_func)` is the type of `void (*)(_IO_FILE*)` whereas `decltype(close_file_func)` is the type of `void (_IO_FILE*)`?

You could check the related code trough https://godbolt.org/z/QK5q3o.

For your convenience, i post the code and the execution output below.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<typeinfo>

void close_file_func(std::FILE* fd);

int main()
{
    std::cout << typeid(close_file_func).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(&close_file_func).name() << std::endl;
}

//Terminate outputs:
//FvP8_IO_FILEE
//PFvP8_IO_FILEE
```

And `echo 'PFvP8_IO_FILEE' | c++filt -t` says `void (*)(_IO_FILE*)` ,

`echo "FvP8_IO_FILEE" | c++filt -t` says `void (_IO_FILE*)`.

And this expression(`std::cout << (close_file_func == &close_file_func) << std::endl;`) is legal.You see, `close_file_func == &close_file_func` returns `true`.

I thought over and over, but i still could not understand. I would be grateful for any hint on this question.

Comment: There's a simpler way to print the type than `typeid` + `c++filt`. See [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4f4277fb1c90fdea)

Comment: or as you know the type `static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(func)>::value, void());`

Comment: @Jarod42  Glad to see you again.Thank you so much.But i could not get the idea.Could you give me a help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might think that both should give the same type as function pointer. Yes, [function-to-pointer implicit conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Function_to_pointer) might be performed in some contexts<sup>1</sup>, but not for `decltype(close_file_func)` (and `typeid(close_file_func)`).

When used with entity, [`decltype`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) would yield the type of the entity; so `decltype(close_file_func)` yield the function type exactly, i.e. `void (_IO_FILE*)`.

> 1) If the argument is an unparenthesized id-expression or an unparenthesized class member access expression, then decltype yields the type of the entity named by this expression.

On the other hand `&close_file_func` takes the address of the function and returns function pointer, then `decltype(&close_file_func)` yields the function pointer type, i.e. `void (*)(_IO_FILE*)`.

---

<sup>1</sup> For [`operator==`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison),

(emphasis mine)

> In all cases, for the built-in operators, lhs and rhs must have either
>
> - arithmetic or enumeration type (see arithmetic comparison operators below)
> - pointer type (see pointer comparison operators below)
>
> after the application of the lvalue-to-rvalue, array-to-pointer and
>   **function-to-pointer standard conversions**.

Function-to-pointer implicit conversion is performed on the left operand so `close_file_func == &close_file_func` is comparing the function pointers.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, `void (_IO_FILE*)` is the type of function whereas `void (*fp)(_IO_FILE*)` is the type of function pointer? Am i right.

Comment: @sunshilong369 Yes.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.One more question raises, why this expression(`std::cout << (close_file_func == &close_file_func) << std::endl;`) is legal?You see, `close_file_func == &close_file_func` returns `true`.Could you give me any hint?

Comment: @sunshilong369 Function to pointer implicit conversion (decay) is performed in this case. It doesn't happen for `decltype(close_file_func)`.

Comment: just for fun, try `decltype((close_file_func))`

Comment: @M.M Then we'll get the 3rd one, function reference, `void (&)(_IO_FILE*)`. IMO it's more confusing than OP's question.